# MYSQL less Than function not working properly

Tags: mysql

I need to get all records those equal and less than 2014-08-31 and greater than 2014-08-01 i used bellow query for this, does anyone has idea ?

```
SELECT * FROM table where user_id = 322 and createdDate > '2014-08-01' and createdDate <= '2014-08-31';
```

Table Value

```
createdDate
2014-08-01 05:14:52
2014-08-27 05:15:08
2014-08-29 02:54:06
2014-08-30 05:57:12
2014-08-31 07:56:13
```

Here my output was

```
2014-08-01 05:14:52
2014-08-27 05:15:08
2014-08-29 02:54:06
2014-08-30 05:57:12
```

i can not get 2014-08-31 07:56:13 this value.
Please anybody know why is this happening ?

Comment: You do realize that strings and dates are not the same thing, do you? You need to use dates for all this to work properly. Also,  `2014-08-31 07:56:13` is actually after `2014-08-31 00:00:00` so the less than or equal works properly in this case...

Comment: yes got this. thanks @ppetereka

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `'2014-08-31'` is interpreted as `'2014-08-31 00:00:00'`

The quickest fix would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table where user_id = 322 and createdDate > '2014-08-01' and createdDate < '2014-09-01';
```

This would list all before 1st September.

The correct solution would be to use dates instead of strings.

Comment: Also I got another Solution. i can i also add one date from using calender.
like date = 2014-08-31 so adding one day it should be 2014-09-31.
this is also help me to solve.

Answer (score 2):

This should resolve..

```
    SELECT * FROM table where user_id = 322 and 
createdDate >= str_to_date('08/01/2014 00:00:00','%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') 
and createdDate <= ('08/31/2014 23:59:59','%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you compare the date with the DateTime field try this.

```
SELECT * FROM table where user_id = 322 and Date(createdDate) > '2014-08-01' and Date(createdDate) <= '2014-08-31';
```